# Update in database row fails without any error in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am retrieving values from the database into the form for update, on the press of submit button.
The values do get retrieved but update process fails without any error.

Here's the code:

```html
<?php
session_start();

$username=$_SESSION['uname'];


$cn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testdb");
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$course = $category = "";
$title = $descp = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if(isset($_POST["pid"]) && !empty($_POST["pid"])){
    // Get hidden input value
    $pid = $_POST["pid"];

    
    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($course) && empty($category) && empty($title) && empty($descp)){
        // Prepare an update statement
        $sql = "UPDATE posts SET course=?, category=?, title=?, descp=? WHERE pid=?";
         
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($cn, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssi", $param_course, $param_category, $param_title, $param_descp, $param_pid);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_course = $course;
            $param_category = $category;
            $param_title = $title;
            $param_descp = $descp;
            $param_pid = $pid;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: CAposts.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
         

    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($cn);
} else{
    // Check existence of id parameter before processing further
    if(isset($_GET["pid"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["pid"]))){
        // Get URL parameter
        $pid =  trim($_GET["pid"]);
        
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE pid = ?";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($cn, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_pid);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_pid = $pid;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
                    /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    
                    // Retrieve individual field value
                    $pid = $row['pid'];
                    $uname = $row['uname'];
                    $course = $row['course'];
                    $category = $row['category'];
                    $pdate = $row['pdate'];
                    $title = $row['title'];
                    $descp = $row['descp'];

                } else{
                    // URL doesn't contain valid id. Redirect to error page
                    header("location: CAposts.php");
                    exit();
                }
                
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
        
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        
        // Close connection
        mysqli_close($cn);
    }  else{
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: CAposts.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>


  <html>

  <head>
    <title>IMEDTalks-Post-
      <?php echo $title;?>
    </title>

    <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="./scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <style>
      /* Make the image fully responsive */
      
      .carousel-inner img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 30%;
      }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="page-header">
              <h2 class="text-center">Update Post</h2>
            </div>
            <p class="text-center">Please edit the input values and submit to update the post.</p>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">


              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <label class="col-form-label col-md-1 offset-3" for="course">Course:</label>
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select name="course" class="form-control" required>
                      <option value="<?php echo $course;?>" selected>
                        <?php echo $course;?>
                      </option>
                      <option value="">Choose any:</option>
                      <option value="comp">Comp</option>
                      <option value="theo">Theory</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <label class="col-form-label col-md-1" for="category">Category:</label>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <select name="category" class="form-control" required>
                      <option value="<?php echo $category;?>" selected>
                        <?php echo $category;?>
                      </option>
                      <option value="">Choose any:</option>
                      <option value="plang">Programming Language</option>
                      <option value="web">Web Technologies</option>
                      <option value="maths">Mathematics and Statistics</option>

                      <option value="others">Others</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="title" class="col-form-label col-md-2">Title:
                        </label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $title;?>" name="title" required>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="desc" class="col-form-label col-md-12">Description:
                        </label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <textarea class="form-control" name="descp" rows="20" required><?php echo $descp;?></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $pid;?>" />


              <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-4 offset-4">
                  <a href="CAposts.php"><button type="button" name="cancel" 
                            class="btn-lg btn-danger">Cancel</button></a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn-lg btn-success">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>

  </html>
```

PS: 
pid is being bought from the previous page where the data is listed in table format, and on the click of the button, that data/post gets loaded into the form for editing using the pid, which is primary key in my database table.
using bootstrap 4.

Edited after first comments.

Comment: You're missing a comma in here: `title=? descp=?`

Comment: BTW get into the habit of not, ever, using select * -- list the columns you want.

Comment: Have you tried checking for any errors? `mysqli_error` is your friend to check that - don't rely on the returned status of any other method

Comment: @aynber  i have fixed that comma error, but after submitting the form, the row gets updated with blank values, and a message no records were found is displayed on the screen, what must be causing this?

Comment: `"sssss"` should probably be `"ssssi"`

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 columns in your query but you only bind 4 of them, so you forgot an **s**

```
$sql = "UPDATE posts SET course=?, category=?, title=? descp=? WHERE pid=?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($cn, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssi", $param_course, $param_category, $param_title, $param_descp, $param_pid);
```

Here a cleaner code for your update:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE posts SET course=?, category=?, title=?, descp=? WHERE pid=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $course, $category, $title, $descp, $pid);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: i have fixed that, but even after submitting the form, the row gets updated with blank values, and a message no records were found is displayed on the screen, what must be causing this?

Comment: This is there's no data in your table using this ID. So your ID ($pid) is not right.

Comment: Can you show me your form ? The HTML part ? Don't forgot that you retrieve $pid by an value from input named pid, so if there no form or you directly access to your PHP code without passing by the form, this is a normal thing.

Comment: The html form part is there in the question post, below the php part.
the pid is still there in the row, but the values of course, category, title, description gets set to blank.
the records are not shown because, on CAposts.php page, i have retrieved the rows with particular mentioned category.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that you are trying to display all your data from DB using

```
// Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE pid = ?";
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($cn, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_pid);

        // Set parameters
        $param_pid = $pid;
```

And also, the value of all your form is using these informations fetched from DB, which is nothing since, i just can't understand. You are trying to fetching all your data using a variable which comming from data of DB itself...

Try something, change the hidden form for your ID and use this (if you have data in db using id 1)

```
<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="1" />
```

Comment: manually providing the pid, as you suggested also didn't worked, still the values of course, category, title, description gets set to blank

Comment: Okay, so your table database is empty. You know you need to have atleast one column in your table right ?

Comment: I was wrong upper, try change this `$param_pid = $pid;` by this `$param_pid = 1` then look if you have some result.

Comment: i do have columns, i meant when i update values of course, category, title, description using the form, they are set to blank in the database table.

Comment: $param_pid = 1 doing this, gives an error, Undefined index: pid

in the following part:
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
                    /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    
                    // Retrieve individual field value
                    $pid = $row['pid'];
                    $course = $row['course'];